# Most Active Contributors in 2017

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors

## Welcome Our SharePoint Stack Exchange Valued Contributors.

We would like to share the **Most Active Contributors (Top 10)** in 2017!

[image]

[image]

You can find the full list at [Stack Exchange Leagues !!](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/105/year/sharepoint/2017-01-01)

---

## Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering,

[image]

We fully appreciate all the great contributions of SE members. Please keep up your valuable contributing!

> **P.S.:** This report will be published Monthly  / Quarterly  / Yearly based on the available data. Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback & precious suggestion!

Comment: @MohammedEl-QassasMVP - can you write up a report for year 2018 as well ? Most grateful !!

Answer (score 4):

Congrats all! Massive credits to the top 10 and especially to the top 3 who together scored more reputation than the top 4-12 did together - that's amazing! But strength is in numbers as in every community, so the efforts of everyone are what make SP.SE a trustworthy and efficient Q&A site.

It sure has been quite a year here. New moderators led by a couple of step-downs from the previous ones, [12.430](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2017+is%3Aquestion) questions which of [386'ish](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2017+is%3Aquestion+spfx) questions asked about [spfx](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spfx) and [934'ish](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2017%20is%3Aquestion%202016) about [2016](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2016), a bit over 1:1 with [12.512](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2017%20is%3Aanswer) answers, [an emerging worry](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/206685/sharepoint-development-past-and-future-how-to-keep-calm/206800#206800) about the future of SP development, [544](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/sharepoint.stackexchange.com) Winter Bash hats, [38%](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2017%20user%3Ame) posts with code against [40.5%](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2016%20hascode%3Ayes) of the previous year, and so on...

It remains to be seen what is the site's trend of 2018, but at least we can effortlessly track it thanks to the introduced [Most Active](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/most-active-contributors)-reports!

<sub>P.s. Found myself at rank **#11** *:confetti:*</sub>